# insert random data from list into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to add a random value ( Not Duplicate ) from list to a table with html form ,
for example this list :
['john', 'lili', 'jason', 'mely', 'adriana', 'taylor']
here is my html form code :

```
<html>
<body>

 <form action="insert.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>

</body>
```

and here is my insert.php code:

```
 <?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user1","123456","db1");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql="INSERT INTO users (name)
   VALUES
  ('$_POST[name]')";

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
  echo "1 record added";

  mysqli_close($con);
```

but i don't know how to do that , thanks

Comment: what happen after all 6 inserted ?

Comment: where you want to get random name in html? or in php ?

Comment: i want to add random name to mysql column with php

Comment: and what about `$_POST[name]` then ?

Comment: i want a html code to pick a name from list and send it to php [name]

Comment: so finally you want this random name in html right ? via javascipt ? and what happen after all 6 inserted ?

Comment: yes in html , and actually the list have 1000 records , the above list is an example and after finished must stop , because i don't want duplicate names ,and i am new in php so i don't know how , thanks a lot for your help

Comment: where you store these names ? in database ? I mean how you will check that it's duplicate or not ? Also what is html file name is it .php or .html ?

Comment: yes in database

Comment: so you can get any value from the list and remove that, will it be fine ?

Comment: yes it is html file and named : form.html

Comment: So now I can say `Use ajax to get random name value from DB and set it to html and then also remove from the database to avoid duplicate name` Right ?

Comment: no i want to pick name from html first

Comment: but i want to pick name from html first

Comment: but this is excellent : so you can get any value from the list and remove that, will it be fine ?

Comment: what happen my friend , is there any solution ?

Comment: It's too broad to make all things, Please try as I said `Use ajax to get random name value from DB and set it to html and then also remove from the database to avoid duplicate name` If you get problem anywhere I am always here for you :)

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: but i  dont know how to do that and i need pick random value from html and then insert to database

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a solution , which you can code later .

1. In the front-end where the form is , don't put textbox , rather a dropdown list of all the names that will come from the array . Here keep a checking whether they appear in the table or not , if yes then don't display it in the drop-down , this will remove duplicate .
2. Now pass the selected value via form and insert the value in the table . Use the code

   if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
       echo "1 record added";
   }
   else{
       die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
   }